# Opening a socket connection from a container on a bridge network to another container running on the host network

Tags: c++, docker, sockets, docker-compose, containers

I am trying to open a TCP connection between two containers that run on the same device.

1. Container A is on a bridge network that includes other containers running. Container A needs to be on this network in order to communicate with these other containers and is the Client of the TCP communication. The bridge network gateway is `10.5.0.1` with Container A addressed as `10.5.0.5`
2. Container B is running on the host network (i.e. `network_mode: host` in docker-compose) and is the Server of the TCP communication.

Some important caveats:

- I can not change Container B's configuration to run on the same bridge network as Container A. This is due to the integration of a 3rd party SDK that is running on Container B. The software connects to a radar device on the host computer's network with the SDK and sends commands/reads status to/from the radar device.
- Previous attempts to move Container B to the bridge network resulted in error codes whenever an SDK function was called in our software. Technical support from the SDK's manufacturer told us that this is due "to the SDK trying to prevent a MitM attack" and they confirmed our results when they tried to use their software within a container running on a bridge network. Their suggestion was to run to our container on the host network.
- I also cannot change the network configuration of Container A to run on the host network as we didn't want to expose the entire contents of this container to the host network. Doing this would solve my problem, but the rest of my team would prefer to avoid this option as there are cybersecurity concerns with this implementation (a valid concern with this deployment).

Docker compose section for Container A:

```
  containerA:
    build: ./containerA
    restart: 'always'
    privileged: true
    environment:
        // ....
    labels:
        // ....
    volumes:
        // ....
    ports:
        // ....
      - 10299:10299
    networks:
      bridge:
        ipv4_address: 10.5.0.5
```

Socket opening on Container A:

```
    // HOST = "10.5.0.1"
    // PORT = 10299

    int sd;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct in_addr ipv4addr;
    struct hostent *hp;

    printf("Creating socket\r\n");
    sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;

    printf("Getting host by addr\r\n");
    
    inet_aton(HOST, &server.sin_addr);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    printf("Connecting\r\n");
    connect(sd, (const sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
```

Docker compose section for Container B:

```
containerB:
    build: ./containerB
    restart: 'always'
    privileged: true
    environment:
        // ....
    network_mode: 'host'
    ports:
      - 10299:10299 // Author's note, fairly certain I don't need to call this when in host mode
```

Socket listening on Container B side:

```
int opt = 1;
struct sockaddr_in addr;
socklen_t addrLen = sizeof(addr);

printf("Begin socket initialization\r\n");
int sockid = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockid < 0)
{
    // Failed to open a socket
    printf("Failed to open socket; ret = %d\r\n", sockid);
    return (ret = sockid);
}

int ret2 = setsockopt(sockid, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt));
if (ret2 < 0)
{
    // Failed to configure socket
    printf("Failed to configure socket; ret = %d\r\n", ret2);
    return (ret = ret2);
}

addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
//inet_aton(TCP_ADDRESS, &addr.sin_addr);
addr.sin_port = htons(targetPort); 

ret2 = bind(sockid, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr));
if (ret2 < 0)
{
    printf("Failed to bind socket; ret = %d, errno = %d\r\n", ret2, errno);
    return (ret = ret2);
}

// Wait for socket connection to be established
printf("Listening on socket\r\n");
ret2 = listen(sockid, 3);
if (ret2 < 0)
{
    printf("Failed to listen for connection; ret = %d\r\n", ret2);
    return (ret = ret2);
}

printf("Accepting connection\r\n");
int newsockid = accept(sockid, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &addrLen);
if (newsockid < 0)
{
    printf("Failed to accept socket connection; ret = %d\r\n", ret2);
    return (ret = newsockid);
}
```

I've tried to have the client node (Container A) target `10.5.0.1` with the socket connection but Container B never proceeds past listening for the socket. Additionally, I've also tried to have the Server node (Container B) listen for any connection on a specified port as well but that also fails to see the incoming connection from Container A.

I've confirmed that the socket code works for both ends when the server node is running on a container locally on my system and have both ends connect to the localhost, so the socket initialization seems to be correct. The problem arises when I try to have the client from the "bridge network" container and the server running on the "host network" container.

**Question:** Is it possible to open a socket connection from the "bridge network" container to the "host network" container?

Comment: The second container that disables Docker networking should be indistinguishable from any other process running directly on the host's network, and the guidance in [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach) should work.  Note that this setup is different using Docker Desktop vs. a native-Linux pure-Docker setup; I don't think the gateway address will work on Docker Desktop, but neither will host networking.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue with that was causing my socket to fail. Apparently, I was getting BlockingIOError that I didn't see before when opening the initial socket. The Python socket client was using `socket.create_connection()` with the timeout value getting set to False, resulting in the socket getting opened in non-blocking mode.

I tried both versions in the python interpreter running from ContainerA and this is what I got:

```
>>> node._socket.close()
>>> node._socket = socket.create_connection(('10.5.0.1', 10299), None)
>>> node._socket.sendall(message.encode())
>>> node._connect_timeout
False
>>> node._socket.close()
>>> node._socket = socket.create_connection(('10.5.0.1', 10299), False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 808, in create_connection
   raise err
 File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 796, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
BlockingIOError: [Errno 115] Operation now in progress
```

Additionally, I removed the port binding on ContainerB and added the setting `pid: 'host'` to the docker-compose file. The `pid` setting was to resolve an issue with a 3rd party SDK I was using with ContainerB. It's not clear to me if the port binding was also causing the issue.

```
containerB:
build: ./containerB
restart: 'always'
privileged: true
environment:
    // ....
network_mode: 'host'
pid: 'host'
```

Adding "pid: 'host'" to the docker compose file allowed the SDK I was using to properly communicate with the intended device.

Comment: Going to leave this answer unaccepted as I think it still needs to be confirmed what settings need to be set in the docker-compose file with the different modes to open the socket. I will accept an answer that confirms why opening the socket in a non-blocking mode caused the error in the first place.